# pdfHTML itext availability

Tags: itext, itext7, pdfhtml

Hi iText support team,

1. I am trying to use pdfHTML for exporting html to PDF using the HelloWorld tutorial given at https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf but my console shows an error reading:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Please let me know the correction I need to make. Attached is a screenshot of my code. 
[image: Screenshot link]

2. I am currently using iText Free Trial version license key. Can I use the pdfHTML without a license key ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some of the iText examples, logging is used to handle errors.

What you're seeing here is that the logging framework is partially loaded.
So it compiles, but at runtime it can't detect any classes that would properly handle logging.

You need to change your POM file to include dependencies on the logging framework of your choice that fits.

Comment: Thanks. Also, Can I use the pdfHTML without a license key ?

Comment: That is a different question. If your application is AGPL (Open Source), then yes. Your entire application's source code MUST be made available to your users if you do not want to use a license key.

Comment: Thanks @AmedeeVanGasse.